# Tomcat web.xml jsp-config for including header and footer

Tags: java, tomcat

In my JavaEE app running on Tomcat, I have some pages that can be access by anybody (for login, register, ...) in the root of app-context and some ones where you have to be logged in. All those pages are mapped to "APP-CONTEXT"/app/*.
What I want is to include header and footer automatically for all pages under /app.
I've read it was possible by setting include-prelude/coda under web.xml file but it doesn't work for me...

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>connexion</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
            <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf</include-prelude>
        </jsp-property-group>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
            <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

I have no error in tomcat's log, the path to header and footer is valid but nothing appear on the screen...
Also, is it possible to match specific ext under a folder using url-pattern (like /app/*.jsp) ?